# Python 3.6 Googleads TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I try to make connection with the [Google Adwords API](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start) using Python 3.6. I managed to install the libraries, got a `developer token`, `client_customer_id`, `user_agent`, `client_id`, `client_secret` and requested succesfully a `refresh_token`.

My googleads.yaml file looks like this:

```
adwords:
  developer_token: hta...
  client_customer_id: 235-...-....
  user_agent: mycompany
  client_id: 25785...apps.googleusercontent.com
  client_secret: J9Da...
  refresh_token: 1/ckhGH6...
```

When running the first python script `get_campaigns.py`, I get the very generic response `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object` in `...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleads-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\googleads\util.py", line 302, in filter`

Other functions like `traffic_estimator_service.get(selector)` produce the same error. Furthermore, when starting the Python script `get_campaigns.py`, I get the following warning, which might explains something:

```
WARNING:googleads.common:Your default encoding, cp1252, is not UTF-8. Please run this script with UTF-8 encoding to avoid errors.
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:googleads.common:Request summary - {'methodName': get, 'clientCustomerId': xxx-xxx-xxxx}
```

I tried many things, but still can't find what causes my error. My settings seem to be right, and I use the examples as provided [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib). Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Use Python2.7 it will solve this error for now.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Python 3.5 and the latest update of the GoogleAds module. Strangely, this used to work! And switching over to Python 2.7 isn't really an option since the whole code base is Python 3 (and used to work fine)

Comment: Google did something wrong in 2to3. I am super busy but you can try and edit the lib code provided by Google it might need some small fix. Namely, it's not allowing to do a regex on a binary string. You can find that file in your error log,

Comment: @Abe I solved this problem for python 3. See my edited answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for now:

One:
Use Python2.7, solved this error for me.

Two:
For python 3

```
def method_waraper(self, record):
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.args:
            arg = record.args[0]
            if isinstance(arg, suds.transport.Request):
                new_arg = suds.transport.Request(arg.url)
                sanitized_headers = arg.headers.copy()
                if self._AUTHORIZATION_HEADER in sanitized_headers:
                    sanitized_headers[self._AUTHORIZATION_HEADER] = self._REDACTED
                new_arg.headers = sanitized_headers
                msg = arg.message
                if sys.version_info.major < 3:
                    msg = msg.decode('utf-8')
                new_arg.message = self._DEVELOPER_TOKEN_SUB.sub(
                    self._REDACTED, str(msg, encoding='utf-8'))
                record.args = (new_arg,)
    return filter(self, record)
googleads.util._SudsTransportFilter.filter = method_waraper
```

This solution changes code provided by google and add utf encoding for the binary string, which solves our problem.